# filter from json multi conditions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a filter by checkbox using js. Taking data from JSON, here is the example

```
[
  {
    "id": 111,
    "name": "Standart Room",
    "img": "rooms_img_1.jpg",
    "price": 126,
    "category": "single",
    "roomType": "room",
    "adults": 1,
    "children": 0,
    "bed": "King",
    "facilities": "Closet with hangers, HD flat-screen TV, Telephone",
    "area": 20,
    "breakfast": false,
    "reservedFrom": "2020-02-07T23:28:56.782Z",
    "reservedTo": "2020-02-09T23:28:56.782Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 112,
    "name": "Standart Room",
    "img": "rooms_img_1.jpg",
    "price": 126,
    "category": "single",
    "roomType": "room",
    "adults": 1,
    "children": 0,
    "bed": "King",
    "facilities": "Closet with hangers, HD flat-screen TV, Telephone",
    "area": 20,
    "breakfast": false,
    "reservedFrom": "2020-02-01T23:28:56.782Z",
    "reservedTo": "2020-02-05T23:28:56.782Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 313,
    "name": "Double Room",
    "img": "rooms_img_3.jpg",
    "price": 320,
    "category": "double",
    "roomType": "room",
    "adults": 2,
    "children": 1,
    "bed": "Twin",
    "facilities": "Closet with hangers, HD flat-screen TV, Telephone",
    "area": 20,
    "breakfast": false,
    "reservedFrom": "2020-03-07T23:28:56.782Z",
    "reservedTo": "2020-03-091T23:28:56.782Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 314,
    "name": "Double Room",
    "img": "rooms_img_4.jpg",
    "price": 320,
    "category": "double",
    "roomType": "room",
    "adults": 2,
    "children": 0,
    "bed": "Twin",
    "facilities": "Closet with hangers, HD flat-screen TV, Telephone",
    "area": 20,
    "breakfast": false,
    "reservedFrom": "2020-03-07T23:28:56.782Z",
    "reservedTo": "2020-03-091T23:28:56.782Z"
  }
]
```

filter it by available date and capacity and put in a new array available rooms

but when try with more conditions, like all available with queen and king and twin bed it doesn't work.

```js
if (isBreakfastRequired && !room.breakfast)
  return false;

if (suiteType == true && room.roomType != "suite" ||
  roomType == true && room.roomType != "room" ||
  suitesAndRooms == true && room.roomType != "suite" && room.roomType != "room")
  return false;

if (room.bed == "King" && !kingBed ||
  room.bed == "Queen" && !queenBed ||
  room.bed == "Twin" && !twinBed &&
  (kingBed || queenBed || twinBed) ||
  kingBed == true && twinBed == true && (room.bed == "King" || room.bed == "Twin") ||
  kingBed == true && queenBed == true && (room.bed == "King" || room.bed == "Queen") ||
  twinBed == true && queenBed == true && (room.bed == "Twin" || room.bed == "Queen")
)
  return false;
  return true;
});
```

I imagine it should be a better solution.

Comment: Which line/part of your code exactly does not work?

Comment: Maybe because `else` ? like in `else if (roomType == true)`

Comment: else if(queenBed == true && twinBed == true && kingBed == true) {
                  avaliableRooms = avaliableRooms.filter(room => room.bed == "Queen" && room.bed == "Twin" && room.bed == "King");
 }

Answer (score 0):

try this for checking kingBed or queenBed or twinBed :

```
if (kingBed == true && queenBed == false && twinBed == false) {
    avaliableRooms = avaliableRooms.filter(room => room.bed == "King");

}
else if (kingBed == true && queenBed == true && twinBed == false) {
    avaliableRooms = avaliableRooms.filter(room => room.bed == "Queen" || room.bed == "King");
}
else if (kingBed == true && queenBed == true && twinBed == true) {
    avaliableRooms = avaliableRooms.filter(room => room.bed == "Twin" || room.bed == "Queen" || room.bed == "King");
}
```

Comment: same story: show only the first found element, here it is King bed, I see results with king bed only

Comment: use a new array to store the filtered result. you are filtering the available rooms array and assign the result to save the variable. If you use new array to store the filtered result it might solve your issue.

Comment: While adding the condition in the filter you cant add && condition because there will be always only one type of bed it may be King OR it may be queen OR it may be a twin.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `else if`'s - replace it with `if`s:

```
if(hasBreakfast == true) {                   
    avaliableRooms = avaliableRooms.filter(room => room.breakfast == true);                   
}

if(suiteType == true) {
    avaliableRooms = avaliableRooms.filter(room => room.roomType == "suite");
}

if(roomType == true) {
    avaliableRooms = avaliableRooms.filter(room => room.roomType == "room");
}

if(suitesAndRooms == true) {
    avaliableRooms = avaliableRooms.filter(room => room.roomType == "suite" || room.roomType == "room");
}

if(kingBed == true) {
    avaliableRooms = avaliableRooms.filter(room => room.bed == "King");
}

if(queenBed == true) {
    avaliableRooms = avaliableRooms.filter(room => room.bed == "Queen");
}

if(twinBed == true) {
    avaliableRooms = avaliableRooms.filter(room => room.bed == "Twin");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solved by this

```
if(isBreakfastRequired && !room.breakfast)
              return false;

            if(suiteType == true && room.roomType != "suite" ||
              roomType == true  && room.roomType != "room" ||
              suitesAndRooms == true && room.roomType != "suite" && room.roomType != "room")
              return false;

            if(room.bed == "King" && !kingBed ||
              room.bed == "Queen" && !queenBed ||
              room.bed == "Twin" && !twinBed )

              if((room.bed == "King" && !kingBed || room.bed == "Queen" && !queenBed || room.bed == "Twin" && !twinBed) && (kingBed || queenBed || twinBed))

              return false;
            return true;
```